# Grid of unequal heights in TailWindCSS

Tags: tailwind-css, grid-layout

Is there a way to achieve a grid of unequal column heights (based on content in each div) using TailWindCSS ?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use `flex` to create a grid of unequal heights within the same column.

Please use full page view to see below code.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="container m-auto p-4">
  <div class="flex flex-row space-x-4">
    <!-- First Col -->
    <div class="flex w-full flex-col space-y-4 bg-red-200">
      <div class="h-40 rounded-lg bg-red-500"></div>
      <div class="h-32 rounded-lg bg-red-500"></div>
      <div class="h-60 rounded-lg bg-red-500"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Sec Col -->
    <div class="flex w-full flex-col space-y-4 bg-blue-200">
      <div class="h-12 rounded-lg bg-blue-500"></div>
      <div class="h-72 rounded-lg bg-blue-500"></div>
      <div class="h-48 rounded-lg bg-blue-500"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Third Col -->
    <div class="flex w-full flex-col space-y-4 bg-green-200">
      <div class="h-28 rounded-lg bg-green-500"></div>
      <div class="h-40 rounded-lg bg-green-500"></div>
      <div class="h-64 rounded-lg bg-green-500"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought I could the heights would be auto calculated based on the content inside it.

Comment: I was looking for a way for the browser/css to auto-calculate the height of the DIV based on the content/text inside it.

Comment: I guess then in that case also there will be a gap after first row. Means the first row will take the space of the div with longest height and rest will will leave a gap untill the second row start

Comment: Long back, I come across a workaround to do this using CSS's grids, when grid was not supported on all browsers. I am not able to recollect the source.

Comment: YOu should check this website https://nerdcave.com/tailwind-cheat-sheet they have built what you want.

Comment: @MagnusEffect such great and useful resource you shared, I think this solves the vertical issue with a very interesting approach, although while this resolves the problem on vertical content fit, this has the limitation for horizontal tiles.